# Leaving confirmation pop up

Tags: javascript

I want to use this code to make users confirm that they want to leave my site:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

But there occurs a problem for me. This script pops up every time the user tries to leave my site. That is too spamy and i need to figure out how to limit the pop up, so it pops only once per user.

Comment: so whats your question?

Comment: Does anyone know how to limit the pop up so it pops up only once per user. (If he decides to stay at the page the first time, then the second time he can leave without being asked to leave. You understand my question now ?

Comment: set a cookie or something upon visit, if they have that cookie already, don't show the popup, if they don't, set the cookie, show popup

Comment: Also, don't use this unless you **really** need to (eg. unsaved changes in a form that would be a pain to lose). Few things are more annoying than being stopped form leaving a page.

Answer (score -1):

To limit the popup for once per user you'll need to set a cookie to track users. If they already have the cookie then don't show the popup, if they do then show it.